# Windows 7 firewall - how to block outgoing connections except login to user domain?

Tags: windows-7, login, connection, notifications, windows-firewall

I tried a great tool **Windows Firewall Notifier** for helping managing all outgoing connections in Windows 7 firewall.

More here: http://www.howtogeek.com/113641/how-to-extend-the-windows-firewall-and-easily-block-outgoing-connections/

It is by default blocking all outgoing connections but with notifications. So whenever any application try to connect out it open small window where I can decide if it should be allowed (temp or permanently).

So far perfect, except of one important thing. Obviously it is also blocking service which stays behind domain login in Windows 7 login screen. So how can I allow that process because obviously at that moment on login screen there is no window opening to allow that process.

I believe it is possible to make a new rule which will allow it, but I have no idea what process (executive file) stays behind login to user domain.

**So how to allow login to user domain in windows 7 firewall when blocking everything else by default?**

Comment: Why don't you just create "allow all" exception for traffic within the network?  In other words if the desination is within the network `allow` it otherwise `disallow` it

Comment: Ramhound - thank you but there is no such option in the notifier. Which I guess means I would have to create such a rule in the firewall settings. No idea how to create it and actually I am not sure that I want allow all the communication in the local network just because of login.